# Автоматическое обновление cron

Tags: php, cron

Есть три *PHP*-файла, в которых с разных источников парсятся *JSON*-данные. Как при помощи *cron* запускать эти файлы в 4 часа утра?

Comment: Cron по ссылкам ходить не умеет.

Comment: А как тогда делают через cron, обновление контента?

Comment: Cron - Это планировщик. Он умеет только в нужное время что-то запускать. Вот это "что-то" и делает всю работу.

Comment: У меня есть 3 PHP файла, в которых с разных источников парситься JSON данные. Вы не подскажите, как тогда их запускать, чтобы не делать этого в ручную :)

Comment: `0 4 * * * то_как_вы_запускаете_ваши_файлы_вручную`

Comment: Спасибо. Сюда "то_как_вы_запускаете_ваши_файлы_вручную" можно ввести линк на php файл?

Comment: @Евгений, нужно с интерпритатором, т.е. если php-файлы помечены как исполняемые и указан условный коментарий интерпритатора, то не надо. В самом простом случае это строка `php %file_path%`

Answer (score 3):

1. Выполните в консоли команду `crontab -e` из под пользователя, под
   которым должны запускаться файлы
2. Добавьте в открывшемся файле строку:

   `0 4 * * *      /path-to-php    /full-path-to-php-file > /dev/null`

   2.1 Чтобы найти `/path-to-php` выполните в консоли `whereis php` и в выводе Вам нужно найти что-то вроде `/usr/bin/php`
3. Установите файлу `/full-path-to-php-file` права на исполнение командой
   `chmod +x /full-path-to-php-file`
4. Перезагрузите крон

Comment: `> /dev/null` – а потом ломаешь голову, почему не работает как надо и ошибок нет, не пишите такую чушь, пишите нормальные логи

Answer (score 0):

Создайте php фаил, который будет вызываться кроном в 4ре утра, и используйте его как контроллер - запускайте таски в ваших остальных файлах. Просто через обращение к функциям...